# Updating JSON file in bulk using Windows Powershell Command

Tags: json, windows, powershell

I have 1000+ json files for each I need to update the existing URLs inside it to new one.

For eg,
JSON filename - `random-env01-123456` (wherein characters after `env01-` is the ID to be appended in the end of URL)

Note: All files with same naming convections with unique IDs

```
"Name" : {
       "URL" : ["http:\\00.00.00.00\\123456"]
```

I ask for the Windows Powershell Command to run once for all files urls to be changed to required one.

Kindly revert.

Comment: Please show us a complete (and valid) JSON document

Comment: PowerShell does have cmdlets for dealing with XML, then there is the .Net namespace that you can use.  ['powershell xml cmdlets'](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27powershell+xml+cmdlets%27&t=hk&ia=web) - ['powershell modify xml'](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27powershell+modify+xml%27&t=hk&ia=web)